# Define a property in Struts1 configuration file to use inside the same config file

Tags: java, struts, struts-1, struts-config

I want to define a property in Struts1 configuration file to use **inside the same config file**. As an example,

**Define the property**

```
<property key='base_url' value='https://host/myapp'/>
```

**Use the property value**

```
<action path="login" type="com.UserLoginAction" name="loginForm" parameter="method">
    <forward name="success" path="{base_url}/login.jsp" />
</action>
```

Is there a possibility to do so in struts1.

Thanks.

Comment: Not that I know of--I'm not aware of a `<property>` element at all. Noting that in your example it's useless since JSPs are local to the app anyway so there's no reason to add a URL--they're not URLs, they're relative file paths.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton. Actually I put this as an example. Anyway I need to find a way to use a property value in struts config file which is defined in same file or a separate property file.